# How to change values of array at initialization in C++?

Tags: c++

I want an array that have new attributed values if the value is x.
I can do that in PHP with that code:

```
$test = array(1=>55, 2=>66);
```

on above code if test[0] = 1, the new value of test[0] is going to be 55.

I want to do that in C++.

Comment: C++ is not PHP.

Comment: Your statement ***if test[0] = 1, the new value of test[0] is going to be 55.*** is entirely wrong. The piece of code you have written will simply create a new array and assign that to `$test` such that `$test[1] = 55` and `$test[2] = 66`. The value (if any) which was earlier assigned to the `$test` variable is not retained

Comment: If you want to replace all `1`s in your array with `55` and `2`s with `66` then you may want the [`std::replace`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/replace/). Or if you want to create an array with attributed values, use [`std::map`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/).

Answer (score 0):

Normal C++ arrays do not have keys. There are always 0-indexed.

But we have `std::map` which is what PHP also use internally for key-based containers.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own attributed values class in C++, so it has that behavior.

You can make it so the behavior is hard coded into the class.  Or if you want to get fancier you can make the class having a value mapping passed in.

Here's an example with the value mapping passed into the class.

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <vector>

using sad_panda = std::logic_error;
using std::cout;
using std::map;
using std::size_t;
using std::vector;

namespace {

class AttributedValues {
    vector<int> v;
    map<int, int> attr_to_value;
public:
    AttributedValues(map<int, int> mapping);
    void set(size_t index, int value);
    int operator[](size_t index) const;
};

AttributedValues::AttributedValues(map<int, int> mapping)
    : attr_to_value{mapping}
{ }

void AttributedValues::set(size_t index, int value) {
    if (index >= v.size()) {
        v.resize(index+1);
    }

    auto iter = attr_to_value.find(value);

    if (iter != attr_to_value.end()) {
        value = iter->second;
    }

    v[index] = value;
}

int AttributedValues::operator[](size_t index) const {
    if (index >= v.size()) {
        throw sad_panda("AttributedValues::operator[] index out of range");
    }

    return v[index];
}

} // anon

int main() {
    auto test = AttributedValues{{{1, 55}, {2, 66}}};
    test.set(0, 1);
    test.set(10, 2);
    cout << test[0] << "\n";
    cout << test[10] << "\n";
}
```